# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

I get the above error when i try to execute the following code in python:

```
statusses = []
reqIDs = []

    for row in c.execute('SELECT id FROM xxx').fetchall():

        for row1 in c.execute('SELECT xxx FROM xxx WHERE xxx IN (?)',(row)).fetchall():
            reqIDs.append(row1)

    for row in reqIDs:

        for row1 in c.execute("SELECT xxx FROM xxx WHERE xxx LIKE '%?%'", (row)).fetchall():
            statusses.append(row1)
```

Output:

```
File "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/REST_xxx.py", line 580, in functionX()
for row1 in c.execute("SELECT xxx FROM xxx WHERE xxx LIKE '%?%'", (row)).fetchall():
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.
```

Comment: A question mark in a string in a statement is not a parameter.